# Migration to the physics exchange

Tags: discussion, migration

Why are classical mechanics questions moved to the physics exchange?

There is a [classical-mechanics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/classical-mechanics) tag here.

Comment: My guess is because they are physics questions.

Comment: I would say that the expectation is that if a physics question is asked on math.SE, the crux of the problem is mathematical as opposed to physical.  If that doesn't seem to be the case, it should be migrated.  As to why even have the classical mechanics tag on math.SE, it's to let potential readers know that some knowledge of classical mechanics is probably necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you give some examples?

Comment: @quid:  Try asking a classical mechanics question on mathematics stack exchange and see what happens.

Comment: I take this as a "no."// Looking a bit through the relevant tag it appears the majority of questions is in fact not migrated. The most recent one that was migrated really did not look like a math question.

Comment: @quid did you downvote my question?

Comment: Yes, as you are unable or unwilling to substantiate your claims. The question appears to be based on a false premise, and seems in any case more like a complaint about one recent migration.

Comment: What's the problem with migration? I feel like its motivation is "We moved your question because we think it'll get a better answer there," which seems like a good motivation so long as its true (*even* if the question *might* get answered here) - and every case I've seen of this falls into that category.

Comment: I searched and found two recent mechanics questions which got migrated to Phys.SE, [1](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165074/31782) and [2](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164287/31782). Note that problem solving questions aren't allowed on Phys.SE, only conceptual questions are. So homwork questions migrated from MSE can be closed there.

Comment: @user103816 These two aren't math questions at all... By the way, 10k users can check the list of recently migrated questions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away). I count six questions migrated to Phys.SE in February. Only [one](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/164776) of them had some amount of mathematical content, and in that case the OP requested themselves for the question to be migrated.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Both of them are classical mechanics questions. Classical Mechanics is a well known field of Mathematics.

Comment: Classical Mechanics is not a field of Mathematics.

Comment: "Classical Mechanics is a well known field of Mathematics." Do you even listen to yourself...?

Comment: I, personally, find this question quite silly (although I want to use stronger terms there).  One might as well ask "Why are we migrating programming questions to StackOverflow, or EE questions to Electronics.SE, or cooking questions to Cooking.SE?"  It's simply a matter of the question being off-topic here and on-topic there.

Comment: @quid: All you did was to dispute the "well-known" part, as noticed by Najib. It might be a part of mathematics which is not at all known to people.

Comment: Not exactly "classical mechanics" but maybe close enough: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/msc/msc2010.html?t=70-XX&s=&btn=Search&ls=s (I'm saying this [tongue-in-cheek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek).)

Comment: @quid My friend was doing B.A in Math and he had the subject called "Mechanics" in the second year. What I remember now is that they were mostly taught 'Classical Mechanics' not relativistic and not 'Quantum Mechanics'. E.g. [here](http://www.dbrau.ac.in/syllabus/UNDER%20GRADUATION%20-%20SYLLABUS/SCIENCE%20FACULTY%20-%20B.SC/B.SC.%20(MATHEMATICS).pdf) is a similar curriculum in which you can see the 'Mechanics' as paper-203. P.S: Please use @-myuserid for your future comments.

Comment: I also found some English countries Math subjects list. [Here](http://www.cie.org.uk/images/92083-2014-syllabus.pdf) you can see at page 18 'classical mechanics topics' covered under the name 'Mechanics'. It seems like Mathematicians use the name 'Mechanics' in place 'Classical Mechanics'

Comment: @user103816 Okay, I use the notification. Sorry I mistook you for OP which is why I did not use it. (To avoid this you might  choose some actual display name.) In some math curricula there are courses on English (as a foreign language), Programming, and all kinds of other things that are obviously not fields of mathematics.  Anyway, obviously, some applications of math (to physics and then often classical mechanics) can be part of a math education, and you can ask about more mathematical aspects here. This does not make you claims more true though.

Comment: @quid Can you show me any curriculum of Bachelors or Master in Mathematics where Mechanics is not a part of it?

Comment: @user103816 [Here is an example (in German)](http://www.uni-muenchen.de/studium/studienangebot/studiengaenge/studienfaecher/mathematik/bachelor/bachelor_pdf.pdf) from on of the leading universities. No mechanics there. Except that you can choose some physics courses if you want to, but instead you can also choose business administration, biology, or philosophy or all kinds of things.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche yes. Perhaps for safety let us add that there are also MSC 2-digit classes for each of Biology, Astronomy, Geophysics, Computer Science, and so on.

Comment: @quid How many years curriculum is it?

Comment: @user103816 3 years. One then could continue with a 2-year master. It is a certainty one can find a master without any mechanics or physics whatsoever. If you insist I will provide further links.

Comment: @quid I do not know German Language. But I believe in what you say. So, I agree that 'Mechanics' is not a hardcore field of Math. By the way is 'Vectors' a proper field of Mathematics? If Mechanics is not Math then I wonder how would one study 'Vectors' properly. I have heard of vector calculus so I guess vectors is a proper part of math, perhaps a part of applied math not pure math.

Comment: @user103816 the notion of a vector space is purely mathematical and typically part of linear algebra. Vector calculus is also not inherently related to physics, it is just calculus in more than one dimension. (Of course physics was important as application and motivation.)

Comment: @Najib _These two aren't math questions at all..._ Do you ever listen to yourself"?

Answer (score 7):

I don't know much about mechanics, but we can generalize what Bye_World says in a comment above to all applied math questions: deciding where to ask is a matter of weight/balance of math vs. application context.

There are fairly simple mechanics problems (the forced pendulum comes to my mind; see [[1]](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/pendulum.pdf)
[[2]](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~banhelyi/CV/Cikkek/10/siam4.pdf)), where the mathematical difficulty/issues far outweigh the fairly simple mechanics one needs to understand to state problem. Not surprisingly, most in-depth work on such problems was published by mathematicians. (To give you an example of [fairly hard] physics-related question that I think was correctly asked here see [How to solve 29 coupled quadratic equations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115373/how-to-solve-29-coupled-quadratic-equations))

On the other hand, if someone is asking a question where they are mostly confused about physical laws and how to apply them, migration is the best choice. There were actually some questions like that that I commented on here, but they appear to have been deleted, so (not having anywhere near enough rep) I can't find & link to them anymore. One [perhaps slighly below] borderline question is [Applying linear algebra to solve a problem in mechanical equilibrium](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103529/applying-linear-algebra-to-solve-a-problem-in-mechanical-equilibrium). Had it been asked on the physics site it might have received an answer by now.